# Error in Power BI Desktop when getting data from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: json, azure, azure-blob-storage, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have json files in one of my containers in Azure Blob Storage. 
For some reason last week I could download these files as a data source into Power BI Desktop and today I keep getting errors even though nothing changed (as far as I know, I am new to this).

This is the error I get:

```
An error occurred in the ‘Sample File’ query. DataSource.Error: AzureBlobs failed to get contents from 'https://smartplugdata.blob.core.windows.net/democontainer/'. Status code: 407, description: 'Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=AzureBlobs
    DataSourcePath=https://smartplugdata.blob.core.windows.net/democontainer
    Url=https://smartplugdata.blob.core.windows.net/democontainer/
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Sometimes I can access the files but then I cannot access the content of the files. Other times I can't even access the files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forefront TMG is security software installed on your network. Something in its policies is blocking the request that you are trying to send to Azure. Talking to your local admin should help you figure out which rule is causing the software to block the request and resolve it.

Comment: does this mean that if I am in another wi-fi I won't have this problem? sorry if it's a dumb question but I am not familiar with this stuff

Comment: Forefront TMG is an enterprise security product, so you aren't on a corporate network you shouldn't.